# Oracle - count records if number of token less than 2

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have records like...

```
    ID | KEY
-------|---------
    1  | 123_456_abc
    1  | 123_xyz
    1  | 456_abc
    2  | 123_abc
    2  | 122_73_zcc
    3  | 123_wer
    4  | 345_23_fhd
    4  | 3453_abc
    5  | ad1fr2h3_abcasd
    5  | ers2g45bb_abc2rtd
    5  | asf23g_abc1_sf45
```

I want `count(ID) where count(tokanize(numeric(KEY),'_')) < 2`

As count(ID) will be `6`

Comment: so, you need the count of records where there are < 2 `_` characters in the `key` column. correct?

Comment: yes, but key should get tokanize for numeric value only

Comment: Is the number of elements in the KEY list variable to more than 3 elements as shown?  Could the number(s) in that list be in any position?

Comment: yes, there could be more than 3 number element at any position

Comment: Are you counting the last record of id 5?  If so, how is "abc1" different from "sf45" to arrive at a count of 6?  Perhaps you should indicate which records you are expecting to be counted with an asterisk in front or something. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM xyz WHERE key NOT LIKE '%_%_%';
```

This should filter all elements which have less than two underscores.

Comment: it would be partial solution since i want count(id) where numeric token count is less than 2, as there will be some records like ad1fr2h3_abc1asd, ers2g45bb_abc2rtd, asf23g_abc1_sf45

Comment: @Cool - please add those test records to your original post then.

Comment: yup.. added those..!

Answer (score 0):

eliminate all records which has more than 1 underscores 
then eliminate the ones which do not start with a number 
then sum it up

```
select sum(cnt) from (
select key, cnt,  id from (
select key, length(regexp_replace(key,'[^_]*','')) cnt, id from table_name
) where cnt < 2

) where regexp_like(key,'[1-9]+(.)*')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select Count(1) from 
(with abc(id,key) as (select '1','123_456_abc' from dual
                     Union all
                     select '1','123_xyz' from dual
                     UNion all
                     select '1','456_abc' from dual
                     Union all
                     select '2','123_abc' from dual
                     UNion all
                     select '2','123_73_zcc' from dual
                     Union all
                     select '3','123_wer' from dual
                     UNion all
                     select '1','345_23_fhd' from dual
                     UNion all
                     select '1','345_abc' from dual

)
select key, length(regexp_replace(key,'[^_]*','')) cntr 
from abc )
where cntr = 1
```